# LightBlue not forgetting UUIDs

Tags: service, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, gatt

I have since changed the UUIDS for my pimrary service, yet LightBlue refuses to acknowledge the change. If I use a new phone, I notice the UUID does change, however if I change it again, LightBlue the new phone is now stuck on the previous UUID. If I press "show" for advertisement data, I notice that the UUID is the correct value!

How do I make it "forget" the old UUIDs

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that the bluetooth on your phone has cached the old UUIDs. 


To reset your phone's cache - 

Turn off Bluetooth

Exit the app completely

Restart Bluetooth 

Start your app again 


If this does not help, delete and reinstall the app.

If that still does not help, you should Factory Reset your Phone.